# Typescript Declaration Merging - Duplicate identifier

Tags: typescript, cesiumjs, definitelytyped

I'm trying to figure out how to extend `@types/cesium`, but it either complains that I have a duplicate type definition in case (a), or it can't find the other Cesium type definitions in case (b).

Note that [index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cesium/index.d.ts) is where the original type `Rectangle` exists, which is incomplete and I wish to extend.

**Case (a)**

> Error: Duplicate identifier 'Rectangle'. *ts(2300)*
>   [index.d.ts(1322, 11)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cesium/index.d.ts): 'Rectangle' was also declared here. *

```
export as namespace Cesium;

declare namespace Cesium {

  class Rectangle {
    static fromCartesianArray(cartesians: Array<Cesium.Cartesian2>, ellipsoid: Cesium.Ellipsoid, result?: Cesium.Rectangle): Cesium.Rectangle;
  }
}
```

**Case (b)**

> Error: Namespace '...Cesium' has no exported member 'Cartesian2'. *ts(2694)*

```
export namespace Cesium {    
  class Rectangle {
    static fromCartesianArray(cartesians: Array<Cesium.Cartesian2>, ellipsoid: Cesium.Ellipsoid, result?: Cesium.Rectangle): Cesium.Rectangle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging does not work between any two elements [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) describes what can be merged with what.

If you want to merge a class in order to add more static methods you need to use class-namespace merging:

```
namespace Cesium {
        export namespace Rectangle {
            function fromCartesianArray(cartesians: Array<Cesium.Cartesian2>, ellipsoid: Cesium.Ellipsoid, result?: Cesium.Rectangle): Cesium.Rectangle;
        }
}
```